# NSTextView not updating using Grand Central Dispatch

Tags: grand-central-dispatch, nstextview, dispatch-async

I need to show the loading percentage of a large file without blocking the user interface. I did some research and found several solutions that use Grand Central Dispatch, with the same code. But unfortunately, it's not working for me.

To run tests, I made a simple exemple with a while loop that update a NSTextView with a percentage.

When I click on the start button, the NSTextView updates once with a random value, then the spinning color wheel of OSX appears and the interface is blocked. When I click on the Stop button nothing happens. By cons, once the loop ends, the NSTextView displays 100 and the console displays twice the word "Stop" as if it had kept in memory the two clicks made.

As several answers use the same GCD code that seems to work for other people, I supposed that maybe the problem is with hardware. I work on a iMac from 2009 running OSX mountain Lion. In the terminal, the number of physical and logical cpu are :

sysctl hw.physicalcpu : 2

sysctl hw.logicalcpu : 2

Thanks in advance for your help. Here is my code :

```
@interface MainViewController ()
{
    NSTextView *label;
    NSButton *startButton;
    NSButton *stopButton;
}
@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)loadView
{
    NSView *aView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 500, 500)];
    [aView setWantsLayer:YES];
    aView.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    self.view = aView;

    label = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(30, 450, 100, 25)];
    label.backgroundColor = [NSColor whiteColor];
    label.textColor = [NSColor blackColor];
    [label setEditable:NO];
    label.font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18.0];
    [label setString:@"0"];

    startButton = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(30, 350, 60, 30)];
    [startButton setBezelStyle:NSSegmentStyleTexturedRounded];
    startButton.title = @"Start";
    startButton.font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0];
    [startButton setTarget:self];
    [startButton setAction:@selector(start)];

    stopButton = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(30, 300, 60, 30)];
    [stopButton setBezelStyle:NSSegmentStyleTexturedRounded];
    stopButton.title = @"Stop";
    stopButton.font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0];
    [stopButton setTarget:self];
    [stopButton setAction:@selector(stop)];

    [self.view addSubview:label];
    [self.view addSubview:startButton];
    [self.view addSubview:stopButton];
}

- (void)start
{
    NSLog(@"Start");

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void)
    {
        //Background thread
        float total = 200000;

        for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        {
            //do some hard work here...
            float percent = ((float)i/total) * 100;

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
            {
                //Main thread (UI update)
                [label setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", percent]];
                [label setNeedsDisplay:YES];
            });
        }
    });

    NSLog(@"END : Start");
}

- (void)stop
{
    NSLog(@"Stop");
}
```

Comment: Which code is faster, the global queue (simple calculations) or the main queue (create a string, draw)? Is there something like "// Do some more hard work here..." in the copied solution?

Comment: I put the comment // Do some hard work here, where I load BVH file data into an array. It can last from 10s to 1 minutes. But In the example I only put a for loop with a big number  to emulate a long task.

Comment: Are you sure that pressing the start button actually executes the `start` method, i.e. is "Start" printed in there logs?

Comment: The main queue can't keep up with the global queue. In a real app, `// Do some more hard work here...` takes time. The big number emulates many very short tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I’m suspecting that your `for` loop in your sample is very hot - ie. it’s calling `dispatch_async` on your main queue almost as fast as it can, which is saturating the UI update thread.

This is a really dumb suggestion, but could you try putting in a `sleep` call before the dispatch onto the main thread? Just 10ms or something. This would allow the UI time to update before the next async call hits.

If the code where you’ve commented ‘do hard work here’ takes enough time to allow the UI to update and receive other events then you should be fine.  I think it’s just your hard coded sample which is saturating the UI.